# Module Federation Vite

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vite, yandex-maps

Does anyone tried to put Vue app into React project using module federation and vite?
My vue app uses vuetify and yandex maps what gives me multiple problems. I thought component will be fully independant and I will just put it into react but no. I have problems with initializing maps in the react (but in vue it is working well), and vuetify. How to implement it in the react or avoid it at all?

```
import MapApp from "map-mfe/App";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { createYmaps } from 'vue-yandex-maps'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

const VueMapApp = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const app = createApp(MapApp)

    app.use(createYmaps({ apikey: "my-api" }))
    app.use(createVuetify())

    app.mount("#vue-app")

    return () => app.unmount()
  }, [])

  return <div id="vue-app"></div>
}

export default VueMapApp
```

In the code above I am trying to put Vue component into react, but still getting "Uncaught (in promise) YandexMapException: You have set up  component without initializing Yandex maps. Please check initializeOn setting or call initYmaps manually before registering this component."